# Create trigger to generate expiration date from foreign value

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a trigger that should calculate the expiration date of a subscription based on what subscription-type you've chosen

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `trigger_expiration_date`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER `trigger_expiration_date` 
BEFORE 
INSERT ON `contracts` 
FOR EACH ROW update contracts c 
inner join contract_types ct on c.id_contract_type = ct.id_contract_type 
set c.expiration_date = date_add(c.date_of_purchase, INTERVAL ct.nr_months MONTH)
```

Whenever I run the code above it's approved, but as soon as I insert anything I'm told that I can't insert because the trigger is invoked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you cannot perform updates like that on the same table that your trigger is operating on.

Instead use the `new` alias to reference the record that is being inserted. From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html):

> Within the trigger body, you can refer to columns in the subject table (the table associated with the trigger) by using the aliases `OLD` and `NEW`. `OLD.col_name` refers to a column of an existing row before it is updated or deleted. `NEW.col_name` refers to the column of a new row to be inserted or an existing row after it is updated.

In your case, you can do it like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_expiration_date 
BEFORE INSERT ON contracts 
FOR EACH ROW
    SET new.expiration_date = (
        SELECT  date_add(new.date_of_purchase, INTERVAL nr_months MONTH)
        FROM    contract_types 
        WHERE   new.id_contract_type = id_contract_type);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know what to look up to find the answer :-)